# Unable to delete dynamically generated ImageView - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

I've got a list of images in my database table. When loading the activity, I read the path of images from the file and create image view instances programatically and add one after the other to my linear layout container. Then for every imageView, when clicked - I open my custom image editing activity and edit it. Once the image is edited and save it in a new file and I delete the old file path in the database. Then it comes back to the image view activity and adds the newly saved image to the container. Since I don't have the control of the imageViews in the container I'm not able to remove the imageView (file before editing) when it comes back to the view activity. But when I quit the application and load it again, it looks into the database and loads the images and everything looks fine. Because I deleted the entry in the database, so there is no view of the deleted (file before editing) image.

eg: (logic alone)

```
for all imagePath in ImagePath
    ImageView imageView(imagePath);
    linearLayoutContainer.addView(imageView);
    imageView.onClick() --> openEditActivity();

 Image Edit ActivityForResult: 
    String path = bundle.getString("newImagepath");
    ImageView imageView(path);
    linearLayoutContainer.addView(imageView);
    imageView.onClick() --> openEditActivity();
```

Comment: You should use ListView and play with clicked item position to delete the row

Comment: Yes. I get it. @SuhailMehta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand how you dont have controll over them. When you create them in first place add some class variable which contains all imageviews in layout. Then when user edits some image you just find that imageview in that container and relace it with new one. Thats one of the ways if i understood you question right way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

do somthing like this:

for all imagePath in ImagePath

```
ImageView imageView(imagePath);
imageView.setId(IMG_ID);//IMG_ID is unique for all images
linearLayoutContainer.addView(imageView);
imageView.onClick() --> openEditActivity();// onclick save CLK_IMG_ID=IMG_ID;
```

Image Edit ActivityForResult:

```
String path = bundle.getString("newImagepath");
ImageView imageView(path);
imageView.setId(IMG_ID);//IMG_ID is unique for all images
linearLayoutContainer.addView(imageView);
imageView.onClick() --> openEditActivity();// onclick save CLK_IMG_ID=IMG_ID;
linearLayoutContainer.removeView(linearLayoutContainer.findViewById(CLK_IMG_ID));
```